# What kind of sampling would this be?

Tags: sampling, survey

A market researcher wants to carry out a survey to determine the popularity of a product in the county.

He visits every house in one large housing estate in the county and gives every member of the estate the survey.

What kind of sampling is this ?

I'm stuck between convenience and cluster.

I'm thinking convenience because it is certainly convenient just going to one estate, give everyone the survey, job done.

But I'm thinking cluster because it is in fact a cluster within the population. But is one cluster enough to be considered cluster sampling ? I thought a few clusters need to be taken.

Comment: While you could consider one house to be a "cluster"... it isn't. Clustered would be a whole neighborhood, district,... not one house.

Comment: @user2974951 It's not one house , it's one large housing estate.

Comment: My bad, I guess if the housing estate is big enough and has a varied group of people, it could be considered a cluster. It would be good to check what kind of people aggregate in these estates.

Comment: @user2974951 Actually I wasn't even sure if the term ''housing estate'' is used outside of British English. Your spelling of the word ''neighbourhood'' without the ''u'' tells me you speak American English. Anyway, I agree with you that it could be considered a cluster but it's unlikely to be representative of the entire county.

Comment: Non-random, and probably not representative of the county.

Comment: @Jason_93 What kind of sampling is it ?